# Infinite producer/consumer via serial port data

Tags: c#, async-await, task, producer-consumer

I'm currently reading in data via a `SerialPort` connection in an asynchronous `Task` in a console application that will theoretically run forever (always picking up new serial data as it comes in).

I have a separate `Task` that is responsible for pulling that serial data out of a `HashSet` type that gets populated from my "producer" task above and then it makes an API request with it.  Since the "producer" will run forever, I need the "consumer" task to run forever as well to process it.

Here's a contrived example:

```cs
TagItems = new HashSet<Tag>();
Sem = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
SerialPort = new SerialPort("COM3", 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
// serialport settings...

try
{
  var producer = StartProducerAsync(cancellationToken);
  var consumer = StartConsumerAsync(cancellationToken);

  await producer; // this feels weird
  await consumer; // this feels weird
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  Console.WriteLine(e); // when I manually throw an error in the consumer, this never triggers for some reason
}
```

Here's the producer / consumer methods:

```cs
private async Task StartProducerAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    using var reader = new StreamReader(SerialPort.BaseStream);
    while (SerialPort.IsOpen)
    {
        var readData = await reader.ReadLineAsync()
            .WaitAsync(cancellationToken)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        var tag = new Tag {Data = readData};
        await Sem.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);
        TagItems.Add(tag);
        Sem.Release();

        await Task.Delay(100, cancellationToken);
    }

    reader.Close();
}

private async Task StartConsumerAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await Sem.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);
        if (TagItems.Any())
        {
            foreach (var item in TagItems)
            {
                await SendTagAsync(tag, cancellationToken);
            }
        }

        Sem.Release();
        await Task.Delay(1000, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

I think there are multiple problems with my solution but I'm not quite sure how to make it better.  For instance, I want my "data" to be unique so I'm using a `HashSet`, but that data type isn't concurrent-friendly so I'm having to lock with a `SemaphoreSlim` which I'm guessing could present performance issues with large amounts of data flowing through.

I'm also not sure why my `catch` block never triggers when an exception is thrown in my `StartConsumerAsync` method.

Finally, are there better / more modern patterns I can be using to solve this same problem in a better way?  I noticed that `Channels` might be an option but a lot of producer/consumer examples I've seen start with a producer having a fixed number of items that it has to "produce", whereas in my example the producer needs to stay alive forever and potentially produces infinitely.

Comment: I don't see how `HashSet` (or anything like it) could ever be thread safe. How can you guarantee that every item is unique if another thread might own one or more of the objects? If you want to get rid of semaphores, couldn't just you ship the data from your Producer as another type and make a hashed entry from it on the Consumer end? Also, (couple questions) wouldn't any SerialPort connection theoretically **never** last forever? and, why does this matter to your consumer? In a producer/consumer model, there should be no problem if the number of consumers is 0.

Comment: Do you have control over the `cancellationToken` that is passed to the `StartProducerAsync` and `StartConsumerAsync` methods? Or it is given to you from above?

Comment: Why don't you just use an `AutoResetEvent` with a `ConcurrentQueue<>`?  That or use _TPL DataFlow_

Comment: @dmedine good question around the `HashSet` - I guess that's the problem - I'm not sure if it's possible for it to be threadsafe or if I should be using some other technique.  The SerialPort could indeed close but in that case I'd need to do some sort of retrying logic to connect again when possible.

Comment: @MickyD I had never heard of an `AutoResetEvent` but am definitely interested in what your flow might look like.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes, I have control over the token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, starting multiple asynchronous operations and awaiting them one by one is wrong:

```
// Wrong
await producer;
await consumer;
```

The reason is that if the first operation fails, the second operation will become fire-and-forget. And allowing tasks to escape your supervision and continue running unattended, can only contribute to your program's instability. Nothing good can come out from that.

```
// Correct
await Task.WhenAll(producer, consumer)
```

Now regarding your main issue, which is how to make sure that a failure in one task will cause the timely completion of the other task. My suggestion is to hook the failure of each task with the cancellation of a [`CancellationTokenSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource). In addition, both tasks should watch the associated `CancellationToken`, and complete cooperatively as soon as possible after they receive a cancellation signal.

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
Task producer = StartProducerAsync(cts.Token).OnErrorCancel(cts);
Task consumer = StartConsumerAsync(cts.Token).OnErrorCancel(cts);
await Task.WhenAll(producer, consumer)
```

Here is the `OnErrorCancel` extension method:

```
public static Task OnErrorCancel(this Task task, CancellationTokenSource cts)
{
    return task.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if (t.IsFaulted) cts.Cancel();
        return t;
    }, default, TaskContinuationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default).Unwrap();
}
```

Instead of doing this, you can also just add an all-enclosing `try`/`catch` block inside each task, and call `cts.Cancel()` in the `catch`.

Comment: That is really useful information - thank you!  Regarding another big question I have - is my use of the `HashSet` to pass unique items around concurrently with the `SemaphoreSlim` a good idea?  It feels a bit wrong but I was unsure of how to best accomplish that.

Comment: @John your current implementation has a behavior. Whether this implementation is a good idea depends on whether the behavior that you get is exactly the behavior that you want. If I had to guess, I would say that it's highly unlikely that what you get is what you want, but on the other hand you haven't provided a higher level description of what you are trying to achieve, so I can't say for sure. Asking multiple questions in a single post is frowned upon here, so I would suggest to post a new question about that (with more text and less code).

Comment: Gotcha, thanks.  I’ll make a new question if it’s needed.